# Slick cannot resolve symbol - leftJoin

Tags: mysql, scala, slick-2.0

Did you have issue with cannot resolve symbol error - leftJoin

I use official docs - [off doc for slick 2](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/2.0.0/queries.html)

coffees **leftJoin** suppliers on ...

My imports

```
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
```

My dependencies

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.2", 
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.2",
```

Should I add any additional dependencies and imports for slick 2 ?

BR!

Comment: Did you properly declare coffees as a `Table`, as mentioned here: http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/2.0.0/schemas.html. Side note, do you know that Slick 3.0 is out ? Consider switching to it as it is the version that is actively maintained

Comment: yes of course I know about slick 3. but by historical seasons I have to use slick 2..

Comment: And yes, I have declaration of the table